# Can an angularjs directive compile a new element which is assigned a second directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

EDIT: Each of the directives below will need to apply ng-model bindings in the elements they create to whatever controller is assigned to the page they are on. I've updated the code to reflect that.

I'm trying to create some dynamic HTML using directives. A simple case worked fine in the case of a single directive but now I'm trying to get a little fancier and I'm not sure how this should work. Looking at the code below, picture an HTML page with some existing content, which then has an element like this defined at the bottom of it:

```
<div directiveOne></div>
```

I had directiveOne compile and append additional elements to the page, and that worked. What I want to do now is to have directiveOne compile the same elements to the page, plus an additional one that itself is assigned a directive. When expanded out, it should end up looking something like this (this is just an example):

```
<div directiveOne>
    <input type='text'/>
    <div directiveTwo>
        <select>
            <option>Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason for the two directives is that there will be some code executed in there to figure out what the elements should actually look like. Ultimately I want directiveOne to make use of a series of little directives and not just directiveTwo.

As of right now, here are the two directives, pared down for (I hope) clarity:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('directiveOne', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: '/basePage.html',
        compile: function(element, attr) {
              var jsonObj = { test: 'TestData' };
              return function(scope, element, attr) {
                    var elem = "<div directiveTwo='"+jsonObj+"'></div>";
                    $compile(elem)(scope);
                    element.append(elem);
              }
        }
    };
});

angular.module('myApp').directive('directiveTwo', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: '/subPage.html',
        compile: function(element, attr) {
            return function(scope, element, attr) {
                // Possibly make changes to subPage.html
                // before returning
                    var elem = "<input ng-model='scopedControllerVar'>";
                    $compile(elem)(scope);
                    element.append(elem);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

To a certain degree this works in that if I inspect the HTML afterwards I see this:

```
<div directiveOne>
    <div directiveTwo="[object Object]"></div>
</div>
```

But the code inside directiveTwo was never executed, and so the div is empty. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Really I just need them both to be in the same scope as the controller assigned to the page that the directives will be applied to. Also, I would like to be able to pass the JSON value in directiveOne to directiveTwo, which is what I was hoping the = would accomplish.

Comment: Got it, I'll update the question with the new scope - will that allow for the JSON val in directiveOne to get passed to directiveTwo?

Comment: HTML with mixed case attributes is illegal. E.g. `<div directiveOne></div>` should not work. What browser are you using that this works?

Comment: Chrome. I'll try just <directiveOne></directiveOne>

Comment: **Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!** If you inadvertently broke the code while composing the example but didn't test it again, you'd want to know that before asking someone else to help.

Comment: The example is the actual code just with the var names changed to make more sense. I now have <directiveOne></directiveOne> sitting in the main page html. When the page loads, it correctly hits the directiveOne compile function, which creates an angular element containing nothing but <directiveTwo></directiveTwo>, then it does the $compile. directiveTwo has a templateUrl that has a test message sitting in it, which I expect to see on the main page, but it never loads. If I inspect the html, I see: <directiveOne><directiveTwo></directiveTwo></directiveOne> but the templateUrl never gets loaded.

Comment: Incidently I get the same behavior in Chrome using <directiveOne></directiveOne>

Answer (score 0):

If the two directives is not related then you can use controller for each scope manipulation. Like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('directiveOne', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    scope: {
        basePageTitle: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: '/basePage.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.basePageTitle = 'This is the base page.'
    }
};
});

app.directive('directiveTwo', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    scope: {
        subPageTitle: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: '/subPage.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.subPageTitle = 'This is the sub page.'
    }
};
});
```

Comment: I like it, but in this case I'm not sure I can do this (though I'm not sure I can't either) as the elements these directives create will need to bind to the page's controller (whatever controller that happens to be) using ng-model. I think if I define controllers for each of them they won't be able to access the original controller, but I admit I'm not really sure.

Comment: Do you want to tightly bind the directive scope in the parent controller? Because i don't think you need a directive for that purpose. You noticed that we used "isolate scope" so that you can reuse the directive you created without knowing it's parent scope. But you can always past any string value (@), model (=) or even a callback function(&) from parent controller to your directives.

Comment: Thanks @Meow3301, I really appreciate the help - based on your comments and george's I think maybe I was overcomplicating what I was trying to do so I'm working on a different approach. I'll keep your advice and tips in mind though, you've been very helpful!